# Discarding a tee element

Tags: python, stream, large-data

I want to "fork" a stream of a large amount of data, in order to look-ahead just a couple of elements.

I was hoping to write something like this:

```
from itertools import tee
stream = # a generator of a very large data stream 

while True:
    try:
        element= stream.next()
        process_element( element )
        if some_condition( element ):
            stream, fork= tee(stream)
            process_fork( fork )
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Reading [the documentation for `tee`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee), though, I'm left with the impression that the `deque` of `fork` will keep growing, even after `fork` has gone out of scope.

Is this the case? If so, is there a way to tell `tee` to "discard" the fork? Or is there another more obvious way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple test script:

```
from itertools import tee

def natural_numbers():
    i=0
    while True:
        yield i
        i+=1

stream = natural_numbers()  #Don't use xrange, cpython optimizes it away
stream, fork= tee(stream)
del fork
for e in stream:
    pass
```

It seems that, at least in CPython, the process' memory doesn't keep growing. [There seems to be a mechanism that detects this situation](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L416).

If, however, you substitute `tee` for the python code [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) states is equivalent...

```
def tee(iterable, n=2):
    it = iter(iterable)
    deques = [collections.deque() for i in range(n)]
    def gen(mydeque):
        while True:
            if not mydeque:             # when the local deque is empty
                newval = next(it)       # fetch a new value and
                for d in deques:        # load it to all the deques
                    d.append(newval)
            yield mydeque.popleft()
    return tuple(gen(d) for d in deques)
```

...memory does keep growing, as expected.

So, my guess is that this will be **implementation-dependent behaviour**

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the implementation-dependent behavior @goncalopp mentions by making a`Tee`class and giving it a`discard()`method:

```
class Tee(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable, n=2):
        it = iter(iterable)
        self.deques = [collections.deque() for _ in range(n)]
        def gen(mydeque):
            while True:
                if not mydeque:             # when the local deque is empty
                    newval = next(it)       # fetch a new value and
                    for d in self.deques:   # load it to all the active deques
                        d.append(newval)
                yield mydeque.popleft()
        self.generators = [gen(d) for d in self.deques]

    def __call__(self):
        return self.generators

    def discard(gen):
        index = self.generators.index(gen)
        del self.deques[index]
        del self.generators[index]
```

Note that since it would now be a class, utilizing it would be slightly different. However when you're done with`fork`, you could get rid of it by calling`tee.discard(fork)`. Here's an example:

```
tee = None
while True:
    try:
        element = stream.next()
        process_element(element)
        if some_condition(element):
            if not tee:
                tee = Tee(stream)
                stream, fork = tee()
            process_fork(fork)
    except StopIteration:
        break

if tee:
    tee.discard(fork)
    fork = None
```

Comment: I did want to avoid a pure python implementation, as it's about 4x slower, but I guess I could do it conditionally depending on `platform.python_implementation`. Thanks!